# Spring Boot Admin Wallboard tile is green even if Health Status is "Down"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

Why is the Wallboard tile of my application not turning red when my /health endpoint returns "down"? When i click on the application tile it does say "Instance DOWN" under Insights/Details but on the wallboard its all green. How can i make it turn red?

Comment: Restarting the spring boot admin server seemed to work and correctly update the health status on the wallboard, i hope this will get fixed in the future

Comment: did you file an issue with an reproducible sample?